# How to customize python matplotlib colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I have generated a `plot` with `colorbar` in python.
 Here is the code that I am currently using:

```
import openmc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

sp1 = openmc.StatePoint('statepoint.550-20.h5')
tally1 = sp1.tallies[1]
flux1 = tally1.mean.ravel()
y = np.reshape(flux1, (200,200))

ax = plt.subplot(111)
Z = ax.imshow(y, cmap=plt.cm.viridis)

divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="10%", pad=0.05)

plt.colorbar(Z, cax=cax)
plt.show()
```

Which generates a plot shown in:
[image]

Now, my question is how do I customize the colorbar?

What I want to do is to set `maximum` and `minimum` value ( say `0.000000` to `0.000050` ) for the `color scale` and I want the plot to show color map as I define the scale, not the scale generated automatically from my array value `y`.

I am running python from mac terminal.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Would `ax.imshow(y, cmap=plt.cm.viridis, vmin=0.0, vmax=0.00005)` result in the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

Normally,    `plt.clim(0.000000, 0.000050)` should work.

Comment: can you add details, i am trying as plt.colorbar(Z, cax=cax)
plt.show() plt.clim(0.000000, 0.000050) plt.show() and it shows runtime error You must first define an image, e.g., with imshow.

Comment: use plt.clim(min, max) before plt.show(). It suppose to apply before showing your graph.

Comment: I did that as mentioned above, that shows the error.

Comment: do it like this way, cbar = plt.colorbar(Z)

cbar.set_clim(vmin=0.000000, vmax=0.000050)

Comment: So, This also not work, with the code posted in a answer below, i added this section >>> Z = ax.imshow(y, cmap=plt.cm.viridis)
>>> cbar = plt.colorbar(Z)
>>> cbar.set_clim(vmin=0.000000, vmax=0.000050)
>>> plt.show()  this shows the default color bar not scaled to my defined scale. Anyway, I sloved it yestedday with matplotlib.colors.Normalize(), so thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it. Here is how am doing now,

```
import openmc
sp1 = openmc.StatePoint('statepoint.550-20.h5')
tally1 = sp1.tallies[1]
flux1 = tally1.mean.ravel()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors
import numpy as np
y = np.reshape(flux1, (200,200)) 
ax = plt.subplot(111)
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=0.000000,vmax=0.000025)
Z = ax.imshow(y, cmap=plt.cm.viridis, norm=norm )
plt.colorbar(Z)
plt.show()
```

Now I have `(0.00000, 0.00001, 0.00002, 0.00003, 0.00004, 0.00005)` label in the scale, and the plot are showing according to the scale color value.  Still, I need a guide on how to increase the label number from 6 to 11 as `(0.00000, 0.000005, 0.00001, 0.000015, 0.00002, 0.000025, 0.00003, 0.000035, 0.00004, 0.000045, 0.00005)`. Thanks.